# SonarQube and scapegoat integration via jenkins

Tags: scala, sonarqube

I have a scala project that is built using maven. I have configured a jenkins job that generates the [scapegoat.xml](https://github.com/sksamuel/scapegoat) in the workspace . My jenkins job is also configured to run a [sonarqube analysis](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven) at the end.

I have also [configured](https://github.com/arthepsy/sonar-scala-extra) the sonarqube to pick the scapegoat xml from the right location. However i do not see any reports in sonar qube. Anybody has any idea if the scapegoat xml generated in jenkins is directly picked by sonar or am i still missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `sonar-scanner` to send the generated files to Sonar??

I had similar issue that my Sonar server doesn't show scapegoat analysis. I got it working on sonarqube-7.2.1 community edition using sonarqube plugin from [sonar-scala](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala). (However, I see you are using [sonar-scala-extra](https://github.com/arthepsy/sonar-scala-extra), I haven't tried that).

*Note:* You need compile [sonar-scala](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala) from `master` as latest release `v6.4.0`, doesn't support **scapegoat** yet.

Once this plugin deployed you need choose Quality profiler as **Scapegoat**